# How to make the GFA file contain sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, assembly, overlap

I'm building an assembler and for this, I have a Fastq file (MinION long-read data) and an overlap file from Minimap2 (converted to CSV), now the problem I'm having is that I'm supposed to do what the Flye assembler does and program this (it's for an assignment so I cant take shortcuts). So I have built a script right now that reads the files and makes a GFA file, and it works, however, the file doesn't contain sequences, so when I try to use the file to make contigs, it goes wrong. Could someone tell me what I need to change?

```
import csv

def make_graph():
    # Define the input FastQ file and overlap.csv file
    fastq_file = "b1_1.fq"
    overlap_file = "myoverlaps.csv"

    # Read the FastQ file and generate the set of k-mers
    kmers = set()
    with open(fastq_file, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("@"):
                continue
            for i in range(len(line) - 31):
                kmer = line[i:i + 31]
                kmers.add(kmer)

    # Read the overlap.csv file and generate the set of edges
    edges = set()
    with open(overlap_file, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            left = row[0]
            right = row[5]
            edges.add((left, right))

    # Create the De Bruijn graph
    graph = {}
    for left, right in edges:
        if left[:-1] not in graph:
            graph[left[:-1]] = []
        graph[left[:-1]].append(right[1:])

    # Traverse the graph to generate the repeat assembly graph
    visited = set()
    stack = []
    for node in graph.keys():
        if node not in visited:
            stack.append(node)
            while stack:
                current = stack[-1]
                if current not in visited:
                    visited.add(current)
                if current in graph and graph[current]:
                    next_node = graph[current].pop(0)
                    stack.append(next_node)
                else:
                    stack.pop()

    # Save the graph as a GFA formatted file
    with open("repeat_assembly_graph.gfa", "w") as f:
        for node in visited:
            f.write("S\t{}\t*\tLN:i:31\n".format(node))
        for left, right in edges:
            if left[:-1] in visited and right[1:] in visited:
                f.write("L\t{}\t+\t{}\t+\t31M\t*\n".format(left[:-1], right[1:]))
```

I know the issue is in the write function, but I can't seem to grasp how to get the sequences, I know it is possible using Networkx as a package, but then my script is so slow is barely functions.
The FastQ file looks like this.

```
@37a77f3b-bcf2-48a0-86e7-a0c5d0a3be95 runid=7f8eec05f1beed68c29c091f78bf84807beb3275 read=73 ch=1132 start_time=2021-01-27T22:52:58Z flow_cell_id=PAG49596 protocol_group_id=210105Chi sample_id=D21-130 barcode=barcode01
ATGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTAAGGTTAACACAAAGACACCGACAACTTTCTTCAGCACCTACACAACAACAATCCATTTAAACTGGTAGTAGTTTATACAATCAGTTTGAAAAGCAAAGAGAGTTACGAAGTTAAAGGACATGGGTTTAGTTATGAATACTAGTGGTCCCAGATGATGTGAAGATGGCGTTTGGTATTTTTAGTAAGGAGAGGATGGTAAGATTAAAATCAACACTGCAGATATGCAGCAATATAATTGGTATAAACAAACTGGTGATGGTAGTTACATTCCTGCTGGGCAGATAAGAAGCACTAGAACAGGAATGGCAGAAAATATGGAAATCAATCATCAACTGGTGGTGGAAATGACTGGGCAAGTGCTGTTGGTGCTGGAAATAATAATGTTGCATGGGGTAAAAAGAATACTGAATGCAGCAACAACTAAGAATGAAGCAGACAAATGCTGCATCAATGTTAATAAATTTTGGTGGTGATACTAGTGACTTTATTCAAAAGTATGGGGTAACACCACAAGAGTATATCACAACTTCACAGGCAGGATATCAATCATCTAACAAAAAGAAGCAGACTGTAATAGCAACCTCCTATGATCCAGATGGTAATGTCATATATGAAGCGGAATGGATGTTTGATAAGGATCCTCTAGTTAAGAAGTCAGATGCTTTTGGAAAGAAGGAAGGACAAAAGACTTGGTTTAAAGTAAAGGATATACAACCAGAGTACCCTAAGAAGAAAGTGCCTAAGTTAAAAAATCTTAGACATCCTAAGAATATGAGAATCAATTCTCTGATAGAGCAAAGAAAATAAAAGTATCATCACAAGATCTTATTCGTAATTATAAAGTATCTCCTCAAGAAGTTGCAGAGAGTATCATGCACTAGTTGATATTATTAATAAGTTTATTGATGATAATCCAGAGAAGATCTGAGATGATTGCTAAAAGAGATATCCTGTTCATGATCCAAGACTCTGTGAGTTGAGATTTTAAATTAGATAGGATGAAGGAAGCATCTGAAAAATATGTTGAGAGTAAGTTCCCAGAGAATAAGAAGGTTACTAGTAGGATAGTAAAGATACTGAAAAAGAATAAAGAGATGACTGATCCTGAGTCATTTACGATGAGCTCCTAGTCCACCAACTTATTCTGACTACCAAGTTAAAGTTGAGAGTCTGCTACTAGGCACTTTAAGAAACCTGTCCAGATAAAAGGCGGCACAAAGGTCATTTTGACAAAACCTTAATATTCTGTTACAATAAATAACCTGAGTGGTAAGGGCAATCCATAAGTCCCCCGATGATACATTAGGCTCAGTATAAGCAACATAAGTGTCCCCACCTCTTACTCCCTAACCAAGACCACGGGGTTATAATGTCTTTTCATACCCAACCTGTAAAAATTACTCCCACCAAATCTCTTTCAAATGACTACTCTTCAAAGAGAGCAAGGTTTGTTGAAGCATAACTGGAGCGAGTTTTGCGAAATTGGGTTACAAGTACAAACAATCGTCTTTATGTCGGTTGGTTTGGAGTACTTATGATTCCCTGCTTGCTGGCTCTGCCACTTGCTTCATAGTAGGCTTTCATTGCTGCTCCTCCTGTCGATATCGATGGGATTCGTGAACCTGTTGCTGGTTCATGTTCAATAACAACATTATCTCAGGTGCTGTTGTTCCATCTAGCAACGCTATCGGTATGCACTTCTATCCTATATGGGGCTGCAACTATCGATGAATGGTTATATAATGGTGGTCCATATCAGTTGGTAATCTTCCACTTCCTTATTGGAATCTCTGCCTACATGGGTAGACAGTGGGAACTATCATATCGTTTAGGTATGAGACCTTGGATCTGTGTTACTTCTCTGCACCAGTCTCTGCTGCTTTCGCAGTATTCCTTGTGTATCCTTTCGGACAGGGTTCATTCTCTGACGGAATGCCTCTAGGAATTTCAGGAACATTTAACTTCATGTTCGTGTTCCAAGCAGAGCATAACATTCTTATGCACCCCTTCCATATGGCAGGTGTAGCAGGTATGTTTTGGTGGAGCACTCTTTAGTGCTATGCATGGTTCACTCGTTACTTCTTCTCTGATCAGGAGACTACCGAGAATGAATCACAGAACTATGGTTATAAGTTTGGTCAAGAAGAAGAGACCTATAACATTGTTGCTGCTCATGGATACTTTGTAGACTTATCTTCCAGTATGCATCATTCAACAACTCTCGTTCACTTCACTTCTTCCTAGCAACATTCCCAGTTGTATGTGTGTGGTTAACCTCAATGGGTATTTCTACAATGGCATTCCAACCTCAATGGATTTAACTTCCAGCCAGTCGATTGTATCGGCAGATGGTAAAGTTGTTCCTACATGGGCAGATGTTCTTAATCGTGCCAACTTAGGTATGGAAGTAATGCTGGGCGTAATGCTCATAACTTCCCACTAGACCTCGCTGCAGCTGAGACTAGTGAAGTTGCACTTGTTGCTCCTGCTGTTGGTTGATAAAATCAATACAATCTGATATAATTAAGGGAACTTCGGTTCCCTTTTTTTATATTTAAAAAATCATACACATTGGAAAAGAAAAAATCCCAAGCACACTCAGATTTGGGAGTGGGAAGAGACTCCTGAGGTCAGGGCAGCACTAGACAA
+
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

@525f7e80-86fe-455e-910a-ac339b637b51 runid=7f8eec05f1beed68c29c091f78bf84807beb3275 read=7656 ch=2180 start_time=2021-01-28T00:35:15Z flow_cell_id=PAG49596 protocol_group_id=210105Chi sample_id=D21-130 barcode=barcode01
AGTGTGCTTGTTCCAGTTTAAAGCATTTGCTAAGGTTAACACAAAGACACCGACAACTTTCTTCAGCACCTGATATTGATAACCAAGTTTGATGATAATCCAGAGAGATCTGAGATGATTGCTAAGAGATATCCTGTTCATGATCCAAGACTCTGTGCTGATTGAATTTTAAAATTAGATAGGATGAAGGAAGCATCTGAAAAATATGTTAGAGTAAGTTCCCAGAGAATAAGAAAGGTTACTAGTAGGATAGTAAAGATACTGAAAAAAGAATAAAGAGATGACTGATCCTGAGTCATTTACGATAGGCTCCCTAGTCCACCAACTTATTCTGACTACCAGAAGTTAA
+
(&'%&$%%&%/0'4.%+-)$&*&+,-0117=7416<<?766;A?55><:23.0-3145587<866'/./'&&&++&'$$/44%%>=:CC?+4768>BDGA><.5''%,:=BBB7@;=CIG:644(146A?DC88><@DC@;;@B=@=<6=;D9<962-/+#782391431)5400244200B8C>B=ABDA:7:=?67469?8>:?66:<()9?@E=>FFEA65DQBME?A,6;<88<CED;?<?=@>6)%%&,13858;=>=88BD73'1CB<EA1%,58874152564-(('-+(%,,&'''''$$%',//3256116,+-21++/09<9=897756;974;5;;2+
```

The above reads are two that match, below is the overlap file for the two

And the overlap file is a basic pdf file converted to CSV which looks like this

```
query_name,query_length,query_start,query_end,strand,target_name,target_length,target_start,target_end,residue_matches,alignment_block_length,mapping_quality,tp,cm,s1,dv,rl
read=73,2677,933,1180,+,read=7656,349,91,339,208,252,0,S,3,2,0,6
```

The Reads above only match ones with eachother forward.

The file contains around 2000 reads, and the overlap file has around 100K lines of overlaps between them if that helps.

The current output is something like this:

```
S   586c576-4f03-450c-b217-36eaac3d7ebd *   LN:i:31
S   40f0113e-7beb-48b9-859c-85675872465 *   LN:i:31
S   2b49baa-9350-427e-9e5c-993f1f9455dc *   LN:i:31
S   76b2be93-e39d-4b55-972e-f8e9903457c *   LN:i:31
S   e2bea4f-0357-4c6d-a9ff-cd409331436f *   LN:i:31
S   8854fe1-a658-4afc-b205-0b27e7ec7cb3 *   LN:i:31
S   1dd4d70-55e2-44ea-a7e4-cc6f8d539743 *   LN:i:31
```

Where it uses the ReadID's however what i would like, what i also see in the flye assembler is

```
H   VN:Z:1.0
S   edge_1  TAAACTAAGATGCAACATTTAGTGAATTCTGATAATGAATGGGGGCAATCGTTCTTCTTTACACTTATACAAACTGTGATGTATTCTTCGCTGATAAATTCAACAATTCCCTCCATATTATCGGGGAGTTTTACTCTTTGACCTCTGGTAAATTGTCGCATGTTAGTTGATAACTTGTGGAGTCTAATAAGTCTACTATGTGTGAAGGAAGAGTTGTATTATCTTTTGTCCATGCACTCTTATAATTCATGATTAGCACCTTAAGTAATGATAACTGTGCATGACTAAGTTGTACATTATAGAGTTGATTGTCCATGAGTTTGTGTTAATTTTTAGGGCGAAATCGTTCATTGGTTAGTTATTACTTAGTGTAAGCAGATTACACTCTTCAATATCAATATCCTCTTCTATTATACCACAAATTCTATTAATATCTTTCTCTGAACTTGCGTCACAATTTAACAACCAACCATCAAATTCTTCTGT
```

So it takes the edges, and gets the sequences that belong there. Incase i havent explained it properly, i am using the FastQ file and Overlap file to build an overlap assembly graph and from this graph id like to make contigs. if i have these contigs im practically done, but i dont seem to be able to get a propper GFA graph.

I hope someone can see where i went wrong and point me in the correct direction

Comment: Can you generate a minimal example of input files and expected output? E.g. a fastq file with two sequences and an overlap file that defines a single overlap between them? This will help greatly in helping you debug your program. Doesn't have to be "real" sequences. it might also help if you quickly summarize hwo your algorithm is supposed to work. The average programmer will know nothing of sequence assembly

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully its a bit better now